# Array.from() mystery

Tags: javascript

Someone can explain this?

```
Array.from(undefined);
// Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Array.from(null);
// Uncaught TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Array.from('Break this up');
// ["B", "r", "e", "a", "k", " ", "t", "h", "i", "s", " ", "u", "p"]

Array.from(123);
// []
```

How come the last example returns an empty array? 123 isn't an iterable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

> Array.from(arrayLike [, mapFn [, thisArg]])

> **arrayLike An array-like or iterable object to convert to an array.**

Comment: if you look at the implementation it comes down to this new Array(0) hence the empty array

Comment: simple 'Break this up' is string and has length, 123 is number does not have length

Comment: In which case it's a fundamental question about JavaScript.  All types that aren't iterable return an empty array, except for null/undefined which are generally taken to mean nothing (empty string or a boolean will also generate `[]`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because how it's defined in the spec:

1. `Array.from` is defined at https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.from, see step 7 `Let arrayLike be ! ToObject(items).`
2. `ToObject` is defined at https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toobject. See it throws for `undefined` and `null`, but does not throw for `numbers`.
3. Then return back to `Array.from` and see that steps 8-13 create and fill an array. But `ToObject` from number is an empty (it does not have `len` property and indexed values) object, hence an empty array is returned.