# Why am I getting different outputs between querySelector and getElementsByClassName using Array.from?

Tags: javascript

```
let buttons = Array.from(document.querySelector('.button'));
// []

let buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('button'));
// (20) [div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div.button, div#equal.button]
```

Why are the outputs different?

Comment: If you want to use `document.querySelector` you should use `document.querySelectorAll` instead for multiple items.

Comment: Additionally, you should not retrieve the elements before they exist.

Comment: Probably because the DOM has not ben built when the query is executed. Impossible to tell w/o the html. Anyway, the first line's call would _never_ return more than a single element.

Comment: You're getting a empty array because `Array.from()` converts a DOM element (returned by `querySelector`) to an empty array. Use `querySelectorAll` as @PabloSilió suggested.

Comment: Thank mate. I got my answer

Comment: `document.querySelector('.button')` alone ought to have returned a single DOM element. By art of how `Array.from` is specified, an empty array is returned. This can be avoided by strictly constraining the use of `Array.from` to iterables or array-like objects. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63569627/array-from-mystery

Answer (score -1):

[document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns a single element.

[document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns the list of elements by classname.

If you want to have same output, you should use `document.querySelectorAll`